# problem setting up mono for android with monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

I have `MonoDevelop 2.6 (Beta 3)` and I have also installed the `android SDK` as per the instructions as well as `mono for android`

Everything installs fine, but the `Mono for Android SDKs` option in MonoDevelop's preferences is missing !

what else do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the add-in is not installed correctly, do the following

```
Tools > Add-in Manager > Gallery > Mobile development
```

You should find `Mono for Android` there, if you don't try re-installing.

Hope it helped.

Comment: ok will give it a try, and acknowledge :) thank you. *feels like I'm talking to myself.. freaky*

Comment: Thanks a ton :) found it under Gallery :)